# Safari - SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, ecmascript-6

This is an error I've never seen before.

Here's a simple repro: https://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/qr0ysmst/3/

```
const x = myVar => {

  console.log(myVar);

  for(let myVar of [1,2,3]){
    console.log(myVar);
  }

};

x(10);
```

Output in Chrome: `10`, `1`, `2`, `3`
Output in Safari: `SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice: 'myVar'.`

Ideas? Is this a bug in Safari?

Edit - Worth noting, I wouldn't ever do this on purpose. I noticed it because I use the ASP.NET bundling & minification system, and that system did this (so my site broke in Safari)

Edit 2 - Interestingly, this works in both browsers

```
let x = 10;

for(let x of [1,2,3])
{
    console.log(x);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/aw37pd2s/1/

Comment: I'm not sure whether this *should* be an error or not, but I think it's bad coding to shadow a parameter like that. You should call the `myVar` variable in your loop something else.

Comment: @Frxstrem I certainly agree - I wouldn't ever do it on purpose. I noticed it because I use the ASP.NET bundling & minification system, and that system did this (so my site broke in Safari).

Comment: What Safari version?

Comment: @AndrewLi I'm using 10.0.3

Comment: Definitely seems like a Safari bug to me. The `let` in the loop should be running in its own iteration-specific environment.

Comment: I have the same problem with Babel an @rgrove/parse-xml@3.0.0 npm package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's a Safari bug. I filed a bug report.

Comment: Jake, did you find any workaround for making it work in Safari? I'm using .Net Bundling and suffering from the same bug. I'm thinking about detecting the browser and serving different bundles (minified for all, non-minified for Safari).

Comment: @yalpertem My workaround for this was to use "var" instead of let for the places that had the issue, or just renaming one of the variables to avoid it.

Comment: @jake It looks like this was fixed sometime in the last 6-12 months, based on when I last tested it. In Safari/Mac v11.1.2 and the version that comes with iOS v11.4.1, I'm seeing the same output in Safari as Chrome. I noticed this because I randomly tested an app (Angular in a .NET MVC wrapper) that hadn't been working in Safari for iOS, and it works beautifully now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mention of 'shadow' variables, but this is the case that tripped things up for me:

[image]

I am reusing `key` inside the loop and 'shadowing' the parameter for the function.

I was able to get both these errors:
`cannot declare a const variable twice`
or
`cannot declare a let variable twice`
by changing the declaration in the for loop.

So the fix for me was easy - to just change `const key` to `const k` for the loop.